# Perform Sum over Conditional Products

Tags: worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

I do have a list like this

```
╔═════╦═══╗
║ 1.5 ║ A ║
║ 2.5 ║ B ║
║ 2.5 ║   ║
║ 5.2 ║ A ║
║ 6.4 ║ C ║
╚═════╩═══╝
```

and want as result:

```
╔═══╦═════╗
║ A ║ 6.7 ║
║ B ║ 2.5 ║
║ C ║ 6.4 ║
╚═══╩═════╝
```

So I want the sum over all elements where A, B, C occur which would correspond to this pseudo code: `SUM( column1 .* ( column2 == 'A' ) )`, `SUM( column1 .* ( column2 == 'B' ) )` etc... How I can I do something like this in LibreOffice?

Comment: @Xen2050, thanks I corrected it. Yes I want to sum the A,B, ... up separately. Those cells which are empty should be added to no one.

Comment: No problem, I might as well delete the comment... I've found a function that looks like it should do what you want too, I'll toss in an answer from Calc's help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for this function:

> ## SUMIF
>
> Adds the cells specified by a given criteria. This function is used to
>   browse a range when you search for a certain value.
>
> The search supports regular expressions. You can enter "all.*", for
>   example to find the first location of "all" followed by any
>   characters. If you want to search for a text that is also a regular
>   expression, you must precede every character with a \ character. You
>   can switch the automatic evaluation of regular expression on and off
>   in Tools - Options - LibreOffice Calc - Calculate.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> SUMIF(Range; Criteria; SumRange)
>
> **Range** is the range to which the criteria are to be applied.
>
> **Criteria** is the cell in which the search criterion is shown, or the search criterion itself. If the criteria is written into the
>   formula, it has to be surrounded by double quotes.
>
> **SumRange** is the range from which values are summed. If this parameter has not been indicated, the values found in the Range are
>   summed.
>
> SUMIF supports the reference concatenation operator (~) only in the
>   Criteria parameter, and only if the optional SumRange parameter is not
>   given.

- From the [Calc help - webpage](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Mathematical_Functions#SUMIF) or built-in <kbd>F1</kbd> help. It's got a TON of useful info, try the search and browse around a little.

So, for example an entry like this:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B5,"A",A1:A5)
```

Would examine cells B1 to B5, and if they equal A (using "=A" works too, could do ">=A" etc), then the corresponding entry in A1 to A5 gets SUM-ed.

- The SUMIF function appears common to LibreOffice, OpenOffice, MS Office... the [MS Office SUMIF help page](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) looks good, and apparently has a [help video](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Video-SUMIF-function-in-Excel-50583A1A-01BC-48E2-ACD2-B428ED2CB66D) too.
- Also see the OpenOffice help page [Conditional Counting and Summation](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Conditional_Counting_and_Summation).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of manually adding SUMIF functions for every value in Col 2, just use a pivot table. I've just added a header row:

[image]

Now. just select the data area (here: A1:B6), select menu `Data` -> `Pivot table` > `Create...`, confirm `Current selection` with <kbd>OK</kbd>, and drag the column headers in the appropriate fields:

[image]

That's it - click <kbd>OK</kbd>. The result looks as follows:

[image]

That's really useful with bigger data tables. Pivot tables come especially handy if you want to apply different arithmethic operations than just summing the values up: you can count the values, calculate the average, and much more.

Comment: Probably an overkill but nice answer. Since you master the arcane _pivot table_ I was wondering if you were able to answer to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/650064/how-to-copy-a-column-with-conditional-format-by-value-libreoffice-4-1) too... BTW not that it was related with pivot table :) but only with LibreOffice.